# Is it possible to batch transactions together?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, transactions, network, fees

In `bitcoin`-land, it's advised to batch transactions to send them to (a) reduce fees and (b) reduce network congestion.

Does the same apply to `ethereum` land? It seems that the `to` can be only one address / account. But can there be many `from`s?

Is there a benefit to doing so?

Comment: individual transaction can have only 1 from, and also only 1 to.

Answer (score 3):

On Ethereum, you can have a smart contract with batch transfer functionality, the function would take two arrays as input arguments, one for addresses and one for values. It would then iterate through the input arrays and call transfer as as many times as your length, however, it is a solidity anti-pattern to interact with untrusted external contracts in one single transaction.

Comment: But an individual transaction can only have one `from` and one `to`?

Comment: yes if you're complying to the ERC20 standard.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to send ether from one address to several addresses in one transaction, but it is not possible to send from many addresses unless they are smart contracts.

In order to send ether to multiple addresses in one transaction, you just need to deploy the contract similar to this:

```
contract BatchSend {
    constructor () public payable {
        address (0x<first address>).transfer (<first amount>);
        address (0x<second address>).transfer (<second amount>);
        ...
        selfdestruct (address (0x<last address>)); // Will send all the rest
    }
}
```

and along with constructor call you will need to pass total amount of ether to be sent.